# wordpress down after changing http to https

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

I bought and installed SSL certificate on the server. After that, I went to WordPress admin settings/general and changed Site Address and WordPress Address from HTTP to HTTPS.
At this point, when trying to save, I got logged out twice and had to log in again.
The site stopped working. I get `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` when I try both HTTP and https address.

Here is what I have tried so far. Nothing is working. Is there anything else I can do?

**In config I added, with my site's address:**

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com'); 
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

**Changing .htaccess file to:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**I made sure that config file does not include:**

```
define(‘FORCE_SSL_LOGIN’, true);
define(‘FORCE_SSL_ADMIN’, true);
```

I disabled all plugins by changing the name of the plugin folder.
I edited wp_options table to make sure it only includes the HTTP address.

The site is still impossible to access. Any other suggestions?

Comment: `‘` != `'`, check your quotes.

Comment: changed to `define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );`  It's still not working

Comment: Ok presuming you also changed `‘FORCE_SSL_LOGIN’` and `‘FORCE_SSL_ADMIN’`. Are you behind a reverse proxy like cloudflare?

Comment: As far as I understand what reverse proxy is, I don't think I'm using it. However, I am pointing my domain nameservers to the hosting provider, and I set up a pointer record in the hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
define(‘WP_HOME’,’http://example.com’); 
define(‘WP_SITEURL’,’http://example.com’);
```

to:

```
define('WP_HOME','https://example.com'); 
define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com');
```

otherwise wordpress will loop between http and https forever.

Comment: I changed it to `define('WP_HOME','http://example.com'); 
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');`

Comment: I also tried `define('WP_HOME','https://example.com'); 
define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com');` Neither works.